# Google map drawing broken in ScalaFx WebView

Tags: scala, google-maps, javafx, scalafx

Circle drawn with google.maps.Circle inside ScalaFx WebView is broken, and not shown correctly (as seen in the screenshot).
When I open the same html in the browser (Google Chrome) circle is drawn correctly. Is there something I need to set in WebView to prevent this and why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. In case anyone else encounters similar, I have solved by uninstalling all Java and Java SE Development Kit programs, and installed Java 8 Update 181, and also Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181.